# Smooth kernell density graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, kernel-density

I am trying to create a graph of a posterior probability. The code that I'm using is:

```
qplot(N2016, geom="density", xlim=c((n_star_2016 -5), (CIs2016[[3]])),
      xlab="Número estimado del total de asesinatos 2016",
      ylab="Probabilidad de la estimación", adjust=5)
```

where N2016 is the posterior probability by 100.000 samples.

The issue that I have is that when I use the "density" kind of plot I get some probabilities at values that are not credible, because my observations are 160. Therefore, I should get a probability of zero before 160.

Graph with adjust=5

[image: img1]

I have been playing with the adjust parameter but this does not seem to be the answer, since the curve is not smooth at all.

Graph with adjust=0.25

[image: img2]

I'm also attaching the graph using histograms to show that the problem is not with data:

Histogram

[image: img3]

Does anyone know how to obtain a smooth-looking curve that does not start before the observations? In this case 160?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `trim` parameter:

```
r <- rnorm(100)
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(r), trim = FALSE) + xlim(-4, 4),
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(r), trim = TRUE) + xlim(-4, 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks